# The style do not works in the render template function

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6

The style do not works in the render template function:

```
h('div', { style: {} }, [
  h('label', "Hello: ", {style: { fontWeight: "500"}}),
  h('label', "world")
])
```

Comment: `fontWeight: 1500` has an invalid value, and therefore is ignored by the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the order of the text and the style tag in the wrong way around.

> ```
> h('label', "Hello: ", {style: { fontWeight: "1500"}}),
> ```

Should be:

```
h('label', {style: { fontWeight: "1500"}}, "Hello: "),
```

Also, 1500 is an invalid value for `font-weight`, this is inside the initial revision of your question, it should be 900 at most, example:

```js
new Vue({
  render: function(h) {
    return h('div', { style: {} }, [
      h('label', {style: { fontWeight: "900" }}, "Hello: "),
      h('label', "world")
    ])
  },
}).$mount("#app")
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.3/dist/vue.runtime.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the params in the correct order:

```
h('label', {style: { fontWeight: "500"}}, "Hello: "),
```

Or you can pass the innerHTML like bellow:

```
h('div', { style: {} }, [
  h('label', { domProps: { innerHTML:"Hello: " }, style: { fontWeight: "500"}}),
  h('label', "world")
])
```

for [detail](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth).